# The login screen doesn't take input from the keyboard or mouse

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse, display-manager

I have upgraded from `Precise` to `Trusty` (via the update manager). My system boots up, but when it comes to login (by entering my password), it doesn't take any input from the keyboard or mouse, and the cursor stops blinking.

Comment: Is it an internal , usb, or wireless keyboard?

Comment: It is USB keyboard

Comment: Can you access BIOS before boot ? maintain `f2`, `f8` or `f12`, it depends, during first seconds of boot. Is the led of "num lock" on ? If so, it will confirm that your keyboard is powered and  recognized   by the computer but not by Ubuntu. Have you test another keyboard and your keyboard on another computer, just to check ?

Comment: The num led is on.yes I can access keyboard during BIOS.it only stops working at login screen (but still the num led is on and mouse's light is also on).I read somewhere that it's due to some acpi error.in BIOS I,selected the latest kernel and pressed 'e' key.then a screen appeared where there were several lines written,then,according to that post,I added acpi=off at the end of 'LINUX' line and pressed ctrl +x,the system booted up but still the problem persisted

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing "Ctrl-F1". Do you see the black screen with a login prompt? (That is called TTY). In that case your desktop environment has been corrupted by the update (it happens sometimes).

If that is the case, maybe you can log in with your username and password from the TTY and try to reinstall (or purge and install again) the desktop environment you are using (Unity?). Or you can try to take a look to the log files and try to fix it somehow.
You could try with:

```
systemctl status lightdm
```

and

```
systemctl restart lightdm
```

Note: For returning to the *frozen* login screen, press (Ctrl-F7).

Comment: Nothing is happening.no pop-up , Still stuck on login screen

Comment: You could try something like: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: how can I do 'sudo' when I can't even login

Comment: I understood that you saw the TTYs, so you can log in with your user on on one of them (for example Ctrl-F1) and continue from there.