# USB keyboard and mouse not working after upgrade of ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 16.10

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, mouse, 16.10

I have a new computer with an ASRock X99 OC Formula mainboard. I started the ubuntu 16.10 boot dvd and noticed that the keyboard is working, but the mouse pointer is only doing some kind of flickering if I move the mouse. I followed many hints on ask ubuntu but couldn't make it working.

I then installed ubuntu 16.04, which worked perfectly fine. Then I tried to upgrade to ubuntu 16.10 and then things were even worse than with the boot dvd, because neither mouse nor keyboard were working at all. I could boot it into systemd.unit=multi-user.target via grub and then the keyboard worked, but the network dhcp did not come up (further problems ...)

Long story short: there seems to be a fundamental issue with my hardware and ubuntu 16.10. It does not seem to be the kernel itself, because the multi-user.target worked. I really tried many things that I found on the internet like "i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset" kernel parameters or "echo -1 > sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend" and other things I found, but nothing resolved the problem.

Did something change between 16.04 and 16.10 in the xserver/display-manager/gui part?

I now simply go back to ubuntu 16.04. I only wanted to let others know if they find this problem. If you have a good hint then I am willing to try it out with the boot dvd once again, but the whole process is just VERY time consuming.

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/q/893930/458410. Not the same versions thought.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly same problem with upgrade from 16.04LTS to 16.10 on an Intel 64bit CPU, usb keyboard and mouse not working from startup.

Luckily, I had Putty remote terminal installed (recommended) on another computer on my LAN, so I could open a remote window. Also found a suggestion to enter:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

This worked perfectly. I had tried `sudo apt update` with no effect, but `sudo apt upgrade` produced an output along the lines that xorg was held back, so I was happy to see xorg involved in the reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a remote terminal and the networking is not properly working in recovery mode. I fixed the problem on Ubuntu 16.04 by switching from graphics mode to text mode as follows.

1. Boot in recovery mode: Press F12 (or other keys displayed during boot time) -> Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choose the latest kernel in recovery mode.
2. Select root (Drop to a root shell prompt) in the recovery menu
3. Stop the xorg service

> ```
> service lightdm stop
> exit
> ```

5. Select resume in the recovery menu. Ubuntu is started in text mode.
6. Install package

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
> sudo reboot
> ```

7. Ubuntu is started in graphics mode by default and the keyboard/mouse are working.

Comment: This helped me, bot only part of the way since step 3 failed because service lightdm was not known and gdm3 was already stopped. Step 5 also failed, because Ubuntu did not start after resume. _However_, instead, you can click on network in recovery menue to activate network drivers, and then execute step 6 right from the root shell in recovery mode! That solved the problem for me after a reboot. :)

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM:

This issue occurred with me on Ubuntu 16.04, perhapse because I used following command while researching to solve the issue of graphics not showing 3D menus etc.:

"sudo apt-get clean" or "sudo apt-get autoclean"

and then "sudo apt-get autoremove" when suggested by the system I guess(??)

which I think removed so many UI related packages from the system.

SOLUTION which worked for me:

1.Boot the sysem in **recovery mode**,
2.Connect network cable to your system to **access internet** since it is needed to download some packages,
3. Check if internet is accessible by typing "**ping 8.8.8.8**" (ping google.com might give unknown host error),
4. If data packets are trasfered then ok, else use following command to set  nameserver temporarily,

**echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf** (Upon successful DHCP connection, it should be overwritten back to the "correct" DNS server which is "127.0.1.1" in /etc/resolv.conf file in my case.)

Check if internet is accessible by typing "**ping google.com**".
5. Once successful, install input packages by running following command:

**sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo reboot**

On reboot, keyboard and mouse are detected and working properly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ubuntu.  Thank you for your efforts but, basically your solution the same as the exisiting one, only with more details and for more critical situations.  I thnk you should rephrase it, explaining what you want to add to exisiting answer(s) and why.